# GCC function name conflict

Tags: c, gcc

I was having some problems with a sample code i was testing, since my abs function was not returning the correct result. abs(-2) was outputing -2 (this, by the way, is suposed to be the absolute value function, if that was unclear)

After getting a bit desperate, i eventually had the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int abs(int x) {
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", abs(-2));
    return 0;
}
```

This does nothing useful but it serves to show my problem. This was outputing -2, when it was expected to output 1.

if i change the function name to something else (abs2 for example), the result is now correct. Also, if i change it to receive two arguments instead of one, it also fixes the problem.

My obvious guess: a conflict with the standart abs function. But this still doesn't explain why the output is -2 (it should be 2, if using the standart abs function). I tried checking the assembly output of both versions (with the function named abs and abs2)

Here's the diff output for both assemblys:

```
23,25c23,25
< .globl abs
<   .type   abs, @function
< abs:
---
> .globl abs2
>   .type   abs2, @function
> abs2:
54c54
<   .size   abs, .-abs
---
>   .size   abs2, .-abs2
71c71,74
<   movl    -4(%rbp), %edx
---
>   movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
>   movl    %eax, %edi
>   call    abs2
>   movl    %eax, %edx
```

From what i understand, the first version (where the function is named abs) is simply discarding the function call, thus using the parameter x instead of abs(x)

So to sum up: why does this happen, especially since i couldn't find a way to get any sort of warning or error about this.

Tested on Debian Squeeze, ggc 4.4.5, and also on gcc 4.1.2

Comment: here is an example in ideone http://ideone.com/YpnkE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCC is playing tricks on you due to the interplay of the following:

- `abs` is a built-in function;
- you're declaring `abs` to return `unsigned int` while the standard (and built-in) `abs` returns `signed int`.

Try compiling with `gcc -fno-builtin`; on my box, that gives the expected result of `1`. Compiling without that option but with `abs` declared as returning `signed int` causes the program to print `2`.

(The real solution to this problem is to not use library identifiers for your own functions. Also note that you shouldn't be printing an `unsigned int` with `%d`.)

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies part of it. i knew about the builtin functions, and i though something like -fno-builtin would possibly solve it, but i didn't know the actual flag name. Still, when using your second solution (declaring the function as signed int) the output of 2 implies that the builtin function is being called instead of mine, which leads to my other question: shouldn't i get a warning about this behavior? In a real, large-scale project, this kind of issue could have been a real headache to identify

Comment: @Naps62: yes, a warning would have been nice, but it seems GCC (even `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`) just won't give you one. Better be careful with your identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

`gcc` optimizes the call to `abs()` to use its built-in `abs()`. So if you use the `-fno-builtin` option (or define your `abs()` as returning `int`), you'll notice you get the correct result. According to [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.7/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) (quoting):

> GCC includes built-in versions of many of the functions in the
>   standard C library. The versions prefixed with _*builtin* will always
>   be treated as having the same meaning as the C library function even
>   if you specify the -fno-builtin option. (see C Dialect Options) Many
>   of these functions are only optimized in certain cases; **if they are
>   not optimized in a particular case, a call to the library function
>   will be emitted**.

Had you included `stdlib.h`, which declares `abs()` in the first place, you'd get an error at compile time.

Comment: The program i posted is not falling back to the builtin function as it would be expected. instead it is simply ignoring the function call, treating abs(-2) as -2. Also, i tried your suggestion to include stdlib.h, and got no compile-time error, the problem remained

Comment: I find that hard to believe, as you are defining a function called `abs()` with conflicting types with the one in `stdlib.h`. Even without any strict or pedantic options, gcc 4.1.2 and 4.4.7 both emit compilation errors.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a lot like [this bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34130), which is from 2007 and noted as being fixed.

You should of course try to compile without GCC's intrinics, i.e. pass `-fno-builtin` (or just `-fno-builtin-abs` to snipe out only `abs()`) when compiling.