# Unexpected function call

Tags: mysql, c, gcc

I'm using **MySQL 5.0.51a** and I uncovered a bug which was causing an infinite loop (ending in a stack overflow and seqgfault) when my program was exiting.

I discovered that if I had a function called `shutdown()`, it would be called by during a call to `mysql_close()`.

I've included a mimimal example C source file and makefile below to show the issue in action.
In the example, `shutdown()` gets called despite not being called by `main()`.

What is going on here? Is my `shutdown()` clashing with a `shutdown()` in libmysqlclient?
If so, is there a reason gcc doesn't know about it?

I'm using gcc (GCC) 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu4)

---

mysql_shutdown.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>

#define HOST "<hostname>"
#define USER "<username>"
#define PASSWD "<password>"
#define DB "<dbname>"

MYSQL *connection;

void shutdown(void)
{
    printf("shutdown called\n");
}

int main()
{
    connection = mysql_init(NULL);
    mysql_real_connect(connection, HOST, USER, PASSWD, DB, 0, NULL, 0);
    mysql_close(connection);

    return 0;
}
```

makefile:

```
mysql_shutdown: mysql_shutdown.c
        gcc  -Wall -Wextra -Werror `mysql_config --cflags` -o $@ $^ `mysql_config --libs`
```

Output:

```
$ ./mysql_shutdown
shutdown called
```

Note that this appears to be the opposite behaviour to that shown in [GCC function name conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087706/gcc-function-name-conflict). In that case the expected function wasn't being called, whereas in my case, a function is being called when it isn't expected.

Comment: Maybe you should try with `gcc -Wall`?

Comment: you are including header of mysql. Compiler just omits other definition because it is weak and yours is strong. ( I think )

Comment: @Bobby I have actually been using "-Wall -Wextra -Werror". I mistakenly didn't include them in the post. I'll edit it now. Anyway, they do not make a difference to the behaviour.

Comment: @gcc What does "weak" and "strong" mean in this context? If I put a conflicting definition of my own, the compiler warns me "error: conflicting types for ‘shutdown’". Why would it not do the same for MySQL's definition (if it exists: it appears to be a function internal to libmysqlclient)? Also, I presume that the error would be caught by linker, not the compiler, when it finds that it has two functions to choose to link to.

Answer (score 1):

What's most likely happening is that, because `mysql_config --libs` is giving you a list of the MySQL library files and the `shutdown()` function is in a *different* object file within the library(s), it's not being bought in.

You have to understand the way most linkers work. What they will do is tie together all the object files that you list explicitly and you end up with a partial executable and a list of symbols that have yet to be resolved.

Then the libraries are searched in an effort to resolve those symbols, by locating the object files within those libraries which can resolve the symbols. Normally what may happen is that you'll find `mysql_close()` in one of the libraries and load up its object file from that library. But that action may introduce *more* symbols that need resolving, which can in turn lead to more libraries being searched.

As an example, let's say `mysql_close()` calls `shutdown()` which is normally provided in one of the MySQL libraries. However, because you've *already* defined it, the loading of `mysql_close()` does *not* result in having an unresolved `shutdown` symbol. So there's no need to go looking for it in any of the libraries.

It *does* result in `mysql_close()` calling a totally different `shutdown()`, the one you provided in your code.